# Rename Index.php

Tags: php

I Renamed the index.php wordpress to index3.php,  because i dont want offline the current site, that also has index.php as name and other CMS platform. But when I click on the internal links as "Services" he takes to the site current site.

Have something that I can set to go to the correct page and after then rename it to index.php when I want go online the new site?

Link: http://www.mc.med.br/index3.php/

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your wordpress installation to a subdirectory and switch back after.

See the [Wordpress Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Comment: There's another way? I hate move the files and config all. Is too much things to do!

Comment: The best way is to seperate different systems and not to mix them up. Otherwise you gonna have some mess. You have to move your wordpress installation only once (Steps 1 to 6 of my link). If you want to go live with it, you just have to copy the `index.php` and `.htaccess` file and adjust the path. These would be the steps 7 to 11.